# pip install has SSL issue in virtualenv with interperter of python27

Tags: python, ssl, pip, virtualenv

**TL;DR
Trying to use pip install within a python27 venv and got SSL connection error.**

I am very new to python development. With the advent of python 3 and all the compatibility issues it introduced, I never felt so lost with so many python 2 codes and documentations active along with python 3 documentations.

So I am working with a python web app (flask based) which should be running on python 2.7.

I am running windows 10 with VS Code.

So I have done all the steps to create a venv folder under my project with the cmd `virtualenv -p "C:\\Python27\python.exe" venv`

When I start doing the `pip install -r requirements.txt`

I am getting following connection error.

> c:\users\path\to\project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:354:
>   SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server
>   Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform.
>   This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate,
>   which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer
>   version of Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>
> InsecurePlatformWarning 
>   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None,
>   read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)':
>   /simple/pip/
>   c:\users\kenzho~1\worksa~1\7eleve~1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:150:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
>   Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

I have tried following ways to address the issue.

`python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/`

But none of them seems to work.

Any body got any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What are versions of Python and pip?

Comment: My system default Python is 3.7. Virtualenv is Python 2.7. The pip running in virtualenv 19 on Python 2.7. thanks

Comment: Still not enough information. What exactly Python 2.7? For `pip` to connect to PyPI Python must be at least 2.7.9, better 2.7.16.

Comment: It is Python 2.7.15.
pip 19.0.3 from c:\path\to\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Python SSL packages.

**Option 1**

Installing the following packages will fix the errors.

```
pip install pyOpenSSL ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```

But this will only work for the system version of Python 2.7.6.
For some reason trying the same fix with a python in a virtual env fails hard. You end up not being able to complete the update because of the SSL error you are trying to fix.

**Option 2**

Upgrade your version of python. The fixes you need have been bundled into [Python 2.7.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/)
Details of the error and fix are in the release notes.